# restful-react post 'mutate is not a function'

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and am trying to use the [restful-react library](https://github.com/contiamo/restful-react) to hit a REST API in a more component-based way.

From the below code snippet I get an error of `mutate is not a function` despite being in the same format as the mutate example ([found here, under the 'mutate' folder](https://codesandbox.io/s/30n66z45mq))

Essentially all I am trying to do is POST JSON of an object like `{name: this.state.name}`.

Note that I have not specified a `path` attribute in the Mutate element because the component is wrapped inside a GET request which sets the base path for all children elements (e.g. I do a GET on path `/items`, meaning that all child RESTful elements start at root `/items` and so I shouldn't need to specify a path if I want to post to `/items`

```
<Mutate verb="POST">
{
    mutate => (<input type="submit" value="Submit" 
    onClick={
        () => mutate({name: this.state.name})
    }
    />)
}
</Mutate>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code snippet you need to specify mutate function like that: `{(mutate, { loading }) => (<input ... your input code ... />) }`. In the snippet `del` is used instead of `mutate`. I presume you might also want to pass only the name to the post url in order to identify the item and call `mutate(this.state.name)` within onClick

Comment: @MihailPanayotov I tried changing the function signature to `(mutate, {loading}) => etc. ` and using `mutate(this.state.name)` but I receive the same 'mutate is not a function' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue myself - I was importing mutate as

`import Mutate from 'restful-react';`

rather than

`import { Mutate } from 'restful-react'`